# How to customize the wordpress menu items in the header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a wordpress menu and then display that menu in the header. There are total 6 pages or menu items in header. Now I want to display 3 of them on left side and other 3 on right side. As I am weak in stylesheet styling so do not know how to divide this menu in two parts.
Here is the code for header:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background: #00C9C9;padding: 20px;">
    <div class="container">
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

<?php
wp_nav_menu( array( 
'theme_location' => 'my-custom-menu', 
 'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'menu_class'        => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
              'list_item_class'  => 'nav-item',
'link_class'   => 'nav-link m-2 menu-item nav-active'
            )
);

?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using two separate menus but in case you don't want / can't do this here's a solution using `margin-left : auto;`

```css
ul {
display : flex;
align-items : center;
justify-content : flex-start;
list-style : none;
width : 600px;
background-color : red;
padding-left : 0;
}

li {
margin : 0 15px;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
margin-left : auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li> Link 1 </li> 
<li> Link 2 </li> 
<li> Link 3 </li> 
<li> Link 4 </li> 
<li> Link 5 </li> 
<li> Link 6 </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Xanthous your answer helped me